# Reference a word table from excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I am attempting to write an excel macro that opens up an rtf document in word and returns the page numbers of specific tables based on a couple of variables (pulldate and rmname).  The following code works perfectly in word VBA (using "activedocument" in place of "wdApp", of course) but it breaks when I try to implement it from excel.

```
Sub find_pulls()
Dim wdApp As Object
Dim pullsheets As Object
Dim totalPullPages As Integer
Dim pg As Pages
Dim start As String
Dim finish As String
Dim rmname As String
Dim tnumber As Integer
Dim pSnumber As String
Dim pEnumber As String
Dim pulldate As String

Set wdApp = CreateObject("word.application")

Set pullsheets = wdApp.documents.Open _
("C:\Users\xxxxx\xxxxxxxx\xxxxx\pullsheets.rtf")
wdApp.visible = True


pulldate = "05/06/2017"
rmname = "503"

For Each cell In wdApp.ActiveDocument.Tables

    If InStr(cell, rmname) > 0 Then
cell.Select
    If Left(wdApp.Selection.Cells(5).Range.Text, 10) = pulldate Then
        tnumber = wdApp.ActiveDocument.Range(0, wdApp.Selection.Tables(1).Range.End).Tables.Count
        Debug.Print tnumber
        Set t = wdApp.ActiveDocument.Tables(tnumber)
        pSnumber = t.Range.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
        Set t = wdApp.ActiveDocument.Tables(tnumber + 1)
        pEnumber = t.Range.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
        Debug.Print "Pull is pg." & pSnumber & "-" & pEnumber
    End If
End If

Next cell

wdApp.Quit SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges

End Sub
```

I get "Value out of range" at the "pSnumber = ..." line.  I am assuming this is because there is no table object in excel as there is in word - is there any workaround to get the values I am looking for?

The goal is to search through the document, (which is always formatted in sets of two tables, one with header information, and another immediately after with line items) and return the end page numbers of the tables that are found. These values will then be used to either copy the table data, or to print those pages. Pulldate and rmname will eventually be variables based on user input.  No option to run the macro directly in word, as the .rtf file is system generated and has to be accessed through a master excel sheet.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you added a reference to the Word object library in your Excel VBA project? If you haven't then start by doing that.  Excel VBA doesn't know the values for constants such as `wdActiveEndPageNumber`, which are defined in the Word object model but not part of Excel VBA.

Comment: I urge you to add Option Explicit to each of your source modules.

Comment: Thanks Tim! That did the trick!

Comment: Rich -  thanks for the heads up, I normally do, just threw this one together quickly and must have forgot!

Comment: I urge you to turn on Require Variable Declaration under Tools | Options in the VBE. Then you won't forget to add Option Explicit.